# Loop thru array to make sure criteria is met on every item

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of items. I want to make sure every item meets a certain criteria.

I wrote this for loop but I'm not sure if it's the most efficient. Is there a better way to do this?

```
let match = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < lastPressed.length; i++) {
  if (lastPressed[i].o.length === 1 && lastPressed[i].n.length === 0) {
    match++;
  } else {
    break;
  }
}

if(match === lastPressed.length) return true;

return false;
```

Comment: use `.every` method

Comment: ... and don't `break`

Comment: Even if `every` is not used, why would you check every item when just **one that doesn't match** should break the loop and return negative result? For thousands of elements in the array and the very first that doesn't match the criteria, this would be much more efficient.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Javascript has a function just for this: [`Array.prototype.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every#:~:text=Description,every%20method%20immediately%20returns%20false%20.).

```js
return lastPressed.every(v => v.o.length === 1 && v.n.length === 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using builtin `every` is the best choice here.

However, assuming you want to do it by yourself (for fun, for learning), notice that you don't have to check every item in the array. It's because the very first item that doesn't match the criteria should fail the whole process.

You just have to reverse the condition then. You don't need the count.

```
for (var i = 0; i < lastPressed.length; i++) {
  if (!(lastPressed[i].o.length === 1 && lastPressed[i].n.length === 0)) {
    return false;
  } 
}

return true;
```

It's exactly your code but the loop terminates when you find the first nonmatching element.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a [`for ... of` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) and exit early.

This approach uses a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and a negated condition for the check.

```
for (const { o, n } of lastPressed) {
    if (o.length !== 1 || n.length !== 0) return false;
}
return true;
```